# git-flow stopped working on windows until echo statement added - why?

Tags: git, shell, git-flow

I have happily been using git-flow on windows until it stopped working.  I'm not exactly sure why.  The error I get is the following:

```
C:\Git\XXXXX>git flow init help
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\git-flow: line 116: /gitflow-shFlags: No such file or directory
```

Where XXXXX is just any cloned repository.  Using "init help" just to show the git-flow commands do not work.

This is where I don't understand... I started to debug the git-flow shell file by putting echo statements scattered through-out.  All of a sudden it works if I put an echo statement anywhere in this block:

```
*MINGW*)
    export GITFLOW_DIR=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
    #echo "Here now?"
    pwd () {
        builtin pwd -W
    }
    ;;
*)
```

The "Here now?" is commented out, and I get the error above about the gitflow-shFlags missing.  When I uncomment that echo statement and retry, I get this:

```
C:\Git\XXXXX>git flow init help
Here now?
usage: git flow init

    Initialize a new git repo with support for the branching model.

    For more specific help type the command followed by --help
```

With that echo statement, all git-flow commands work.  without it, none of them work and I get the shFlags missing error... What am I missing?

I don't understand the shell script so I don't know why this is happening.  Probably a very easy explanation...